# Where to put android.jar into jetty

Tags: jar, jetty

I'm trying to add the android.jar file to jetty 9.2.1, since I'm using android classes in a service. I tried to put it in the \webapps\project\WEB-INF\lib folder which resulted in a 500 error/ runtime exception. Then I tried to put it into \lib\ext which doesn't trigger any error but somehow stops any output from the particular class using the andoid import.

Could you give me a tipp where to include the jar? Other jars added into WEB-INF don't result in runtime exceptions.

Here is the stacktrace from when I try to put it into WEB-INFO:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!
    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:7)
    at org.sercho.masp.meta.api.json.JSONConverter.getModelAPIRequest(JSONConverter.java:179)
    at org.sercho.masp.meta.api.json.ModelAPIJSONServlet.doPost(ModelAPIJSONServlet.java:325)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:751)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1666)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.server.WebSocketUpgradeFilter.doFilter(WebSocketUpgradeFilter.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1636)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:564)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:578)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:221)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1111)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:183)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1045)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:199)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:109)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:98)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:461)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:284)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:244)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:534)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:607)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:536)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like your not able to run android classes on your IDE, since the implementations in android.jar are only stubs.